# Compare 2 strings and change color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am really not sure how should i go about this. I get 2 string from database comma seperated as below

```
string1 = "DD,CC,FF"
string2 = "DD,XX,FF"
```

I will bind string1 to html table.

you can see that 2 strings are different. What i want to do is to find string2 in string 1 and then highlight only the changed part of string.

So my output will be 
   string1 = DD,**CC**,FF

So my table will show whole string but will highlight value "CC" in the table.

How should i go about this? I am open to use jquery or javascript.

Comment: does the order matter, for example what if string1 was "DD,CC,FF" and string2 was "FF,XX,DD" ?

Comment: @mrida order doesnt matter

Comment: does it always have the same formats ? with comma separated ? or it can be any two strings ?

Comment: @Dilantha always comma seperated

Answer (score 3):

Compare each comma seperated value, if they are not the same, wrap with a tag of some kind :

```
function checkStrings(str1, str2) {
    str1 = Array.isArray(str1) ? str1 : str1.split(',');
    str2 = Array.isArray(str2) ? str2 : str2.split(',');

    for (var i=0; i<str1.length; i++) {
        if (str1[i] !== str2[i]) 
            str1[i] = '<b>' + str1[i] + '</b>';
    }
    return str1.join('');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/as5wa/)

or if order doesn't matter :

```
function checkStrings(str1, str2) {
    str1 = Array.isArray(str1) ? str1 : str1.split(',');

    for (var i=0; i<str1.length; i++) {
        if (str2.indexOf(str1[i]) == -1) {
            str1[i] = '<b>' + str1[i] + '</b>';
        }
    }
    return str1.join('');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/as5wa/2/)

Comment: exactly what i want but you have generated html in javascript code. I have defined table in html. Can you show how to bind it?

Comment: @Happy - You have to get the strings from your table and then replace the first string with the new string etc. Show me the table, and I'll show you how to replace the strings ?

Comment: its normal html table and i have binded value with knockout observable. for example see http://jsfiddle.net/as5wa/3/

Answer (score 0):

Split both the strings by "," and then run a nested loop to check whether each entry in string1 is available in string2. While looping you could add each entry in string1 in an object and mark it as true or false depending on the availability. Then print out the contents in the object with formatting you prefer.

Comment: Is it possible to show this? can you post fiddle for this? I will be very thankful to you